# How can I search and replace text that looks like Perl variables?

Tags: regex, perl, search

I'm really getting my butt kicked here.  I can not figure out how to write a search and replace that will properly find this string.

String:

`$QData{"OrigFrom"} $Text{"wrote"}:`

Note: That is the actual STRING.  Those are NOT variables.  I didn't write it.

I need to replace that string with nothing.  I've tried escaping the $, {, and }.  I've tried all kinds of combinations but it just can't get it right.

Someone out there feel like taking a stab at it?

Thanks!

Comment: Show the actual regex that doesn't work.

Comment: Maybe try reading the documentation on perl regex instead of blindly trying different random combinations in an attempt to get it right.

Comment: davr,

Thanks for the really useful comment. Do you not think I didn't try learning it first.  I'm generally familiar with regexs and spent a good amount of time reading tutorials and documentation on it.  

If you get tired of "people wasting your time" try to avoid these useful comments that waste even more of your time.  Just move on and stop being a troll.

Comment: we have no idea what you've tried (or if you've tried anything) because you didn't show examples of how far you've gotten. Given the circumstances, davr's reaction is justified.

Answer (score 4):

No one likes [quotemeta](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/quotemeta.html)? Let Perl figure it out so you don't strain you eyes with all those backslashes. :)

```
 my $string = 'abc $QData{"OrigFrom"} $Text{"wrote"}: def';
 my $escaped = quotemeta '$QData{"OrigFrom"} $Text{"wrote"}:';

 $string =~ s/$escaped/Ponies!/;

 print $string;
```

Answer (score 3):

I originally thought that wrapping your regex in `\Q`/`\E` (the quotemeta start and end escapes) would be all that you needed to do, but it turns out that `$` (and `@`) are not 
allowed inside `\Q...\E` sequences (see http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/perlre#Escape_sequences).

So what you need to do is escape the `$` characters separately, but you can wrap everything else in `\Q ... \E`:

```
/\$\QQData{"OrigFrom"} \E\$\QText{"wrote"}:\E/
```

Comment: The last `\E` is optional. The end of the regex will also mark the end of the quotemeta sequence.

Comment: Looks like a good soultion for the OP's problem, so $string = '$QData{"OrigFrom"} $Text{"wrote"}:'; while(<>){$_ =~ s/\Q$tring//g;} will work.

Comment: quotemeta() doesn't have the same restriction as \Q. You said it but didn't use it :)

Answer (score 1):

regex using escape character \ would be

`s/\$QData\{"OrigFrom"\} \$Text\{"wrote"\}://;`

full test code:

```
#!/sw/bin/perl     

$_='$QData{"OrigFrom"} $Text{"wrote"}:';

s/\$QData\{"OrigFrom"\} \$Text\{"wrote"\}://;

print $_."\n";
```

outputs nothing but newline.